# Select2 4.0 JSON search not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-select2

After many hours, I finally got the json file to load and to display properly, including the flag icons using Select2 4.0, which looking at how simple the code turned out to look is ridiculous.

But now, for some reason the search function isn't working. I cannot search through any options.

Hopefully it's quick and easy and I can punch myself in the head for not spotting it earlier.

HTML:

```
<select id="country_select" class="form-control"></select>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        function formatCountry (country) {
            if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
            var $country = $(
                    '<span><img src="/assets/img/flags/' + country.code.toLowerCase() + '.png" class="flag" /> ' + country.text + '</span>'
            );
            return $country;
        };

        $('#country_select').select2({
            templateResult: formatCountry,
            templateSelection: formatCountry,
            ajax: {
                url: '/assets/json/countries.json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term,
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function(country) {
                            return { id: country.id, code: country.code, text: country.name };
                        })
                    };
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
```

JSON:

```
{
"id":53,
"code":"CW",
"name":"Curaçao",
"iso_alpha_3":"CUW",
"iso_numeric":531
},
{
"id":54,
"code":"CX",
"name":"Christmasøya",
"iso_alpha_3":"CXR",
"iso_numeric":162
},
{
"id":55,
"code":"CY",
"name":"Kypros",
"iso_alpha_3":"CYP",
"iso_numeric":196
},
```

Comment: what does the json and html look like

Comment: I updated with the JSON, HTML is already there. I've tried it on a fiddle without any CSS and loading the same data, and search doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 1):

Select2 expects that your results will be filtered on the server side, so it doesn't do any matching of its own when working with AJAX.

Given that your JSON is static, I would recommend just pre-loading it using `$.ajax` and then using the `data` option instead of `ajax` to load it into Select2.